# How to implement velocity transformation?

Tags: ros, navigation, transforms, velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

i have the velocity topic /cmd_vel, and it's the type geometry_msgs::Twist, it is given in the object reference frame, and now i need to transform the velocity to another frame, such as my robot's base frame. How can i do that, if i know the translation and rotation between the two frames?

I think it is different from position transformation, because velocity is 6 dimension and position only 3.

Does someone have this knowledge? Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192273/how-to-implement-velocity-transformation?/) by [Qt_Yeung](https://answers.ros.org/users/13976/qt_yeung/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2014-09-09

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can think of linear velocity as a vector with three components. If velocity is given in some frame, and you want it in another frame, it's the same as just giving the vector in the target frame's coordinate system. The tf TransformListener has a handy transform for doing this. It's called transformVector.

http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/tf/html/c++/tf_8cpp_source.html#l00466

Put the three components of linear velocity into a vector and transform it to the target frame.

Alternatively, you can put the values in a point and just rotate them using the rotation in the target frame's transform (and *only* the rotation). This should work for the angular velocities as well (e.g., a robot that has positive yaw velocity in its body frame and is rolled over -90 degrees in the odom frame will have positive pitch velocity in the odom frame).

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Qt_Yeung](https://answers.ros.org/users/13976/qt_yeung/) on 2014-09-09**:
Do you mean:

- Velocity transformation only depends on frame rotation, but not translation?
- I can divide the Twist velocity type into two separate vectors, linear velocity vector and angular velocity vector, each with three components, and multiply them by rotation matrix separately?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-09-10**:
Yes to both your bullet points. Apologies if I was unclear.

Not knowing exactly what you're trying to do, though, it's probably a good idea to check out the code review posted by @tfoote. You can also review some of the tf transform utility methods to see what they're doing.

**Comment by [claudione](https://answers.ros.org/users/38266/claudione/) on 2018-10-30**:
But does transformVector apply a translation to the velocity vector?

**Comment by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on 2020-05-31**:
@Tom Moore, Hi, do you know if transforming the linear velocities get affected by the angular velocities?
If I have a TF Tree `A-->B--->C`, where A is the root node and C is the grandhchild of A. I want to transform the velocity vector v(a twist message that has both linear and angular component) from  C frame to A frame. So, in order to find the linear veclocity vector of v from C to A, do I go about by just multiplying the v.linear with transformation matrix of B and then with transformation matrix of A ? Or should I account for the effects of angular velocity of v.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2020-06-15**:
Are you asking about whether this is necessary mathematically, or whether r_l accounts for it?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is code in tf for transforming twists (6dof) in tf but commented out. http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/tf/html/c++/transform__listener_8cpp_source.html

It's commented out due to lack of clarity of the twist message representation: http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Reviews/2010-03-12_API_Review

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-09-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Qt_Yeung](https://answers.ros.org/users/13976/qt_yeung/) on 2014-09-10**:
It is commented out, so it is not added into Hydro? Do i have to transform twists with my own code?

Such as:

tf::Vector3 out_rot = transform.getBasis() * twist_rot;

tf::Vector3 out_vel = transform.getBasis()* twist_vel + transform.getOrigin().cross(out_rot);

**Comment by [rayane](https://answers.ros.org/users/30174/rayane/) on 2019-08-26**:
@Qt_Yeung
As far as I understood, if we have a transformation matrix that transforms Frame_2 (F2) to Frame_1(F1) given by: T= [R T ; 0 0 0 1] where R is the rotational matrix and T is the translational matrix then a vector V2 with coordinates in F2 is expressed in F1 by : V1 = [R ass(T)*R ; 0(3x3) R] V2 where ass is the skew symetric matrix.
so from this we notice that the first three components of the velocity which is the linear one depend on the translational vector T !!Is what I was saying wrong!!!
but why these lines are added:

```
geometry_msgs::TwistStamped interframe_twist;  lookupVelocity(target_frame, msg_in.header.frame_id, msg_in.header.stamp, ros::Duration(0.1), interframe_twist); //\todo get rid of hard coded number
```